# postgres metric imperial conversion

Tags: postgresql

Is there any extension of hidden standard way to convert the above?

Eg `select some_float at measurement system 'imperial'` as we do `time zone`, or `convert_ms(some_value,'litre', 'pint')` or any other? Of course it would require additional data types like "weight", "volume", "distance" and rules to apply before outputting the value.

I don't expect `locale` to help here, because it need calculations, not just symbol before currency, order in date or symbols to separate thousands or so. But we can `SET timezone` and it calculates the difference (even considering daylight saving time), so there is a chance.

Answer (score 3):

You mean an extension for annotating data with dimensional units. https://github.com/ChristophBerg/postgresql-unit is one such package, but it sticks to the SI system. The scary part is how it creates one SQL data type for any number of different measurement types; postgis does a similar thing with geometry, but it can be constrained. [dimensional and unit analysis in SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224770/dimensional-and-unit-analysis-in-sql-database) has some other discussion on the topic. [GNU units](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/) does a pretty good job at trying to translate for many units and an even better at showing how hopelessly complex it is (there are, for instance, about 20 different ounces). So when converting meters to "imperial", does that mean feet, furlongs, or screw gauge? And of course, when we request data from SQL it's typically for further processing, so we want a consistently parseable data type. Very few systems use SQL to generate presentation formatting directly.

Comment: Found a plain way to constrain a column dimensionally using postgresql-unit: `constraint islength check ( dimension(data) = meter(1) )` worked. I suspect there are neater options.